# Screen resolution changes after wake-up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, desktop

Often when I put my **Windows 7** [64 Bit] PC to sleep and then wake it up, my log-in screen changes size. After i hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and log-in, my Desktop has huge Icons and the open windows are so big that they take all of my screen size. I have to wait for like 10~20 seconds before the monitor automatically brings back the original size/resolution. The problem is that i have lot of programs/icons on my Desktop and every time this happens some of my icons get moved to some other place on my Desktop so i need to bring them back manually to their original place. This problem does not occur every time after i wake-up my PC, but quite often. Has someone similar experience ? Does someone know a solution to this ?

---

My graphic card is **NVIDIA GeForce GT 545**. And my monitor is Dell U2412M [24 LCD]. I have updated my graphic card and the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar problem in Vista, the fix was turning off the screensaver or setting it to blank.

Another option that comes to mind is installing monitor drivers.

Comment: My screensaver is turned off, so that is not the problem. I will try to download/update my Monitor Driver [Dell U2412M] and report back.

Comment: I have installed again a Dell Monitor Driver and the PowerNap Software, and now the problem has gone.

Answer (score 3):

Incase it helps any future Googler' of this question (though not the exact issue described), Windows was changing the resolution of my monitor but then not changing it back automatically. Furthermore, the scaling (amount of space the display took up) seemed wrong.

The solution in my case was to change the scaling options of the monitor. Mainly I had to change the monitor settings from "Maintain aspect ratio" to "Maintain Display Scaling" as in the picture below.

[image: Intel graphics control panel - maintain display scaling]